# Identification of problem in graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose a directed graph *G=(V,E)*. I am interested in computing the smallest subset of nodes *V'* such that:

1. Every node *n* in G is reachable from at least one node in *V'*, with a directed path
2. Every edge *e* in G is reachable from at least one node in *V'*, with a directed path
3. Again, *V'* is the smallest subset that satisfies the above properties

comment 1: Nodes in *V'* are considered reachable  by definition.

comment 2: I suppose property 3. is already implied by property 2., but I added it to make sure there are no exceptions.

comment 3: Nodes with no links at all are also in *V'* for the same reason

comment 4: Nodes with no incoming links are in *V'* as they are not reachable by any other means

Questions:

- Is there a name for this problem in the literature of graph theory?
- Are there efficient algorithms to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An algorithm for solving this problem is given [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/70688). To wit: find the strongly connected components of the directed graph and pick one vertex from each "source" component. If you're not familiar with strongly connected components, the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strongly_connected_component) might be helpful. I'm not aware of a name for this problem.